# SQL Server union behavior with columns

Tags: sql-server

It is possible to get a result like this from N tables (this example has 3 tables)

The table 1 not always has the most rows :

Result

```
Table1Id  Table2Id  Table3Id
-----------------------------
1         33        Y12
2         43        M34
3         23        R77
4         56        NULL
5         NULL      NULL
```

From

```
Table 1           Table 2          Table 3  

Id Description   Id Description   Id   Description
--------------   ---------------  -------------------
1  A             33 XX            Y12  Algo
2  B             43 YY            M34  Something
3  C             23 ZZ            R77  Cosa
4  D             56 FF 
5  E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `full join` and `row-number()`:

```
select t1.id as Table1Id, t2.id as Table2Id, t3.id as Table3Id
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum)
      from t1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum)
      from t2
     ) t2 full join
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum full join
     (select t3.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum)
      from t3
     ) t3
     on t3.seqnum = coalesce(t1.seqnum, t2.seqnum);
```

There are other methods, but this should suffice.